# Binding dynamically created menu items to ICommand from Button.ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

OK, a definite newbie here with WPF, and obviously need to keep learning more about MVVM, my code wasn't specifically designed that way, but I did designate one class to be the interface and controller for the GUI, whereas the model code resides in another set of classes. Have been scouring the web for examples, and questions similar to mine, of which there are plenty, but after three days of running through the maze I'm asking for help.

What I need is a simple dropdown menu, with items that can be dynamically updated (its an app that talks to a USB device, so however many are available should show up along with their device ID and serial number), and the currently selected item should show up on the Button (or whatever implementation of Dropdown menu I end up with). In this example, I just create a static list but that same list would be dynamically updated later on in the full app.

What I have so far looks like it is on the right track: I get the currently selected device id string to show up on the Button, and on pushing the Button, I get the list of all available devices (it doesn't bother me much that the currently selected device shows up redundantly in the list). However, I am not able to hook into any event when an item is selected, and thus can't update the item in the button, or do anything else for that matter.

My XAML below. Note that this was roughly hacked together, and there are some things in here that make no sense, like "IsActive" for the "IsChecked" property, that came from examples. The big problem is that as far as I can tell, none of the Setter properties in the ContextMenu.Resources seem to be doing anything at all...tried changing the fontsize to no avail. And the really big problem, of course, is that the "MyCommand" binding isn't working, that method never gets called.

```
    <Label Content="Device Selected:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Height="25"/>
    <Button x:Name="DeviceSelMenuButton" Content="{Binding DeviceID_and_SN, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="25,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" FontSize="14" Click="DeviceSelMenuButton_Click">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceID_SN_Collection, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ContextMenu.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="SelectDeviceStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
                       <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding RelativeSource Self}"/> 
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsActive}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.Resources>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

And the code from MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CustomDeviceGUI _customDeviceGui = new CustomDeviceGUI();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _customDeviceGui;
    }

    private void DeviceSelMenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // " (sender as Button)" is PlacementTarget
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as Button);
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void SomeMethod(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO Somehow get the index of the selected menu item (collection index, 0-based)
        //     int selIndex = (sender as Button).ContextMenu.Items.IndexOf    ??         
        _customDeviceGui.UpdateDeviceID("RelayPro id updated");
    }

}
```

And the GUI code:

```
class CustomDeviceGUI : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Declare the event 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { }; 
    private string _deviceDisplayString;
    private ICommand _updateMenu; 
    List<string> ControllerDeviceList = new List<string>();

    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> _DeviceID_SN_Collection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();

    // CTOR
    public CustomDeviceGUI()
    {
        ControllerDeviceList.Add("CustomDevice Device 1");
        ControllerDeviceList.Add("CustomDevice Device 2");
        ControllerDeviceList.Add("CustomDevice Device 3");
        ControllerDeviceList.Add("CustomDevice Device 6");
        UpdateDeviceID(ControllerDeviceList[0]);
    }

    #region CustomDeviceGUI Properties

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> DeviceID_SN_Collection
    {
        get
        {
            _DeviceID_SN_Collection.Clear();
            foreach (string str in ControllerDeviceList)
            {
                _DeviceID_SN_Collection.Add(str);
            }
            return _DeviceID_SN_Collection;
        }
        private set 
        {
            _DeviceID_SN_Collection = value;
        }
    }

    public string DeviceID_and_SN
    {
        get
        {
            return _deviceDisplayString;
        }
        private set
        {
            _deviceDisplayString = value;
        }
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_updateMenu == null)
                _updateMenu = new MyGuiCommand();

            return _updateMenu;
        }

    }


    #endregion

    #region Public Methods


    public void UpdateDeviceID(string deviceID)
    {
        this._deviceDisplayString = deviceID;
        RaisePropertyChangeEvent("DeviceID_and_SN");
        RaisePropertyChangeEvent("DeviceID_SN_Collection");            
    }

    #endregion

    protected void RaisePropertyChangeEvent(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        try
        {
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //  ... TODO Remove this catchall or find specific exceptions
        }
    }


    public class MyGuiCommand : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //   Debug.WriteLine("Hello, world");
            int hmm = 3;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged // was ;
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
    }


} // class CustomDeviceGUI
```

Comment: Managed to hack together a solution. I get the ancestor part to some degree, but don't know why ContextMenu.Resources didn't work, or why in the XAML below the DataContext didn't work either -- notice I had to repeat the full binding for the command:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the changes I had to make were in XAML. Primarily it was a matter of using the ancestor to get the right data context. I also switched to ContextMenu.ItemContainer instead of ContextMenu.Resources.

```
   <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="MenuItem"> 
         <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}"/>
      </Style>
   </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score -1):

Eventough I'm not sure I think that the:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

binding needs a [RoutedUICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routeduicommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

EDIT:
Another thing that i have noticed is that you don't set any command bindings before. Like this:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="MyCommand" Executed="Execute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

just an example you can set CommandBindings to many others controls.

Comment: I tried:  <ContextMenu.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="SelectDeviceStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
     <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyRUICommand}"/>, and added the following code to the DataContext class:         private static RoutedUICommand myRuiCommand = new RoutedUICommand("MyRUICommand", "MyRUICommand", typeof(ApplicationCommands));
        public static RoutedCommand MyRUICommand
        {
            get {return myRuiCommand;}
        } but above statement still doesn't get hit. I also tried the Window.CommandBindings but I would need to create an ApplicationCommands I think